# Pure dynamic pages - is it a feasible approach

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website and considering using pure dynamic pages, i.e. no html files and everything is handled by a router in javascript and the DOM elements are all created and inserted to the document by javascript.

I'm just wondering whether it's a good idea. IMHO, events can be attached to DOM elements when they are created, which may make the code more readable. And the static and dynamic parts might be better incorporated. But the page format may become unclear. And I'm not so sure whether performance will be compromised.

Is anyone aware of any websites that actually use this approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: bit of an open ended question. I think its a nice idea, but not really practical. If you started developing a site this way you would probably become frustrated and just hard code your html again, the old fashioned way ;).

Comment: Also it would probably not work very well with search engines.

Comment: Why not just use a server technology (php, asp.net)?  These have been specifically designed to serve dynamic pages, and remove the problem of the static v dynamic parts.  Building something dynamic in pure javascript, whilst clever, wouldn't be practical IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but you're probably looking for something like any number of the new-age JavaScript front-end MVC frameworks:

- http://angularjs.org/
- http://meteor.com/
- http://backbonejs.org/
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/), a javascript library, which separates representation(HTML) and logic(js), making the code clear and easy to understand.
It also supports integration with major javascript libraries.

### pure.js Example

#### HTML template

```
<div class="hello">
<span class="who"></span>
</div>
```

#### Rendering directive

```
{
  "span.who":"who"
}
```

#### JSON Data

```
{
  "who":"Hello Wrrrld"
}
```

#### The resulting HTML

```
<div class="hello">
<span class="who">Hello Wrrrld</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Check a fully dynamic time planning app, built on top of this library at https://beebole-apps.com/?lang=en_US&demoPure&demo